# Is there a sublime keyboard shortcut to go to the very last tab?

Tags: tabs, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to mimic the behavior of Chrome's ctrl+9 shortcut.
It goes to the tab of highest index.
Sublime has a command select_by_index.
Is there a way to get the max index so I can make a key binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make a simple sublime plugin (Tools > New Plugin...)

Packages/User/last_view.py

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class LastViewCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.focus_view(self.window.views()[-1])
```

Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap

```
[
  { "keys": ["super+9"], "command": "last_view" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many tabs are open, you could use ALT-[NUM] to jump to the last open tab. [NUM] must be substituded by the Number of the last tab.

Comment: I want to be able to go to the last tab even if there are more than 10 tabs

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible without an extension. A short alternative could be ALT-1, CTRL-PGUP.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I do now